# How can I call a function defined in a bash shell script from a C program

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, shell

I have

```
    #!/bin/sh

    func1()
    {
        echo "This is func1 from shell script"
    }

    func2()
    {
        echo "This is func2 from shell script"

    }
```

I want to call func1 and func2 from a C program. Can I do that ?

Comment: unless you're writing a loadable builtin, no.

Comment: @ormaaj How sure are you ?

Comment: @ormaaj Can you please elaborate about loadable builtin?

Comment: @abc [Using and Writing Bash Dynamically Loadable Built-In Commands](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/). You can write C code that accesses bash’s internal APIs, compile the C code into `.so`s, and load them into bash with the `enable` builtin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is unlikely to be a good idea, but I suppose you could write something like this:

```
if (! fork()) { // TODO fork can return -1 on error; should check for that
    execl("/bin/sh", "-c", ". FILE && func1", (char *)NULL);
    // TODO should check to make sure execlp successfully replaced the process
}
```

where `FILE` is the name of the `.sh` file that defines `func1`. The above will spawn a child process, and replace that child process with an instance of Bash (or whatever your shell is) with the arguments `-c` (meaning "the script to run is the next argument") and `. FILE && func1` (which is the script; it means "run the commands in `FILE`, and if that succeeds, then run the command `func1`").

For more information:

- [about `fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html)
- [about `execl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html)
- [about `.`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

Comment: This also worked: system("source /home/abc/cpractice/test_functions ; func1 ; func2 "); Where is the documentation for the ; syntax used here?

Comment: @abc: `;` is just a way of separating commands. You can use `\n` instead if you prefer. (The two are not completely equivalent in all cases, but they're equivalent in *most* cases.)

Comment: Note that if the script contains anything other than function declarations (i.e. if it's anything like a normal script), that will get executed as well. As @ruakh said, this is unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: Probably better to use `&&` instead of `;`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Good point, thanks; I've made that change now.

Answer (score 2):

A little simpler than using fork / exec is the stdlib "system" command.

See [man 3 system](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/system/).

Assume your bash functions are in file "/tmp/scripts.sh" ...

```
system("bash -c \". /tmp/scripts.sh ; func1 ; func2\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recive the exit code of executing script, you should use system, else use vfork + exec*